# Linking problem Melodic, compiling multiple .cpp files into single

Tags: ros-melodic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble constructing a node that has several C/CPP files that should be linked into a single.  I have googled around for about 1/2 day and I think I have the CMakeLists.txt file correct (obviously I don't).

The files in question build and link correctly outside of ROS (cpp -o SolTrack Soltrack.c Soltrack_RiseSet.c testfn.c -lm), which mean there is something I am missing about the linking options in the CMake file.

The error I am seeing, is below.  Excerpts from the CMake file are further below (I cannot attach a file yet).

---

> solar_track.cpp:(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to SolTrack_RiseSet(Time, Location, Position*, RiseSet*, double, int, int)
> solar_track.cpp:(.text+0x342): undefined reference to `SolTrack(Time, Location, Position*, int, int, int, int)'

---

> find_package(
> catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
> roscpp
> std_msgs
> ${PROJECT_NAME}
> )

> catkin_package(
> INCLUDE_DIRS include
> '#  LIBRARIES solar_track
> CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
> '#  DEPENDS system_lib
> )

> include_directories(
> include
> ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}  
> )
> > 
> > add_executable(  
>    ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
> src/SolTrack.c
> src/SolTrack_RiseSet.c
> src/solar_track.cpp
> )
>
> target_link_libraries(
> ${PROJECT_NAME}_node  
>    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
> m #math library
> )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332505/linking-problem-melodic,-compiling-multiple-.cpp-files-into-single/) by [Hardyn](https://answers.ros.org/users/45468/hardyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the problem was that I was using a classic C "library", which was upsetting the C++ compiler.

After changing my searches a bit, I discovered this fact and the remedy is actually quite straight forward...

```
extern "C" 
{
  #include "myheader.h"
}
```

Apparently C and C++ is treated differently and the compiler needs to be told this explicitly.

---

Originally posted by [Hardyn](https://answers.ros.org/users/45468/hardyn/) with karma: 26 on 2019-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1